# Android Vision Api - Barcode Formats

Tags: android, barcode, vision

I have followed https://github.com/wax911/Vision-Barcode-Scanner/tree/master/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples this git to implement vision api into my application. I can successfully detect the bar code and QR code, but facing problem with the formats. Below is my implementation:

BarCode initialization:

```
 BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE |
                Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.UPC_E | Barcode.UPC_A | Barcode.CODABAR).build();
        BarcodeTrackerFactory barcodeFactory = new BarcodeTrackerFactory(mGraphicOverlay, autoCapture ? this : null);
        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(
                new MultiProcessor.Builder<>(barcodeFactory).build());
```

After barcode detection, I am trying to identify the format which is been detected.Below is the code

```
public void updateList(Detector.Detections<Barcode> barcodeList) {
    this.barcodeList = barcodeList;
    final SparseArray<Barcode> detectedItems = barcodeList.getDetectedItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < detectedItems.size(); i++) {
        Log.e("Value", "------>" + detectedItems.valueAt(i));
        final Barcode barcode = detectedItems.valueAt(i);
        final int value = detectedItems.valueAt(i).valueFormat;
        switch (value) {
            case Barcode.DATA_MATRIX:
                Log.i("Value", barcode.rawValue);
                break;
            case Barcode.QR_CODE:
                Log.i("Value", barcode.rawValue);
                break;
            case Barcode.CODABAR:
                Log.i("Value", barcode.rawValue);
                break;
            case Barcode.UPC_E:
                Log.i("Value", barcode.rawValue);
                break;
            case Barcode.UPC_A:
                Log.i("Value", barcode.rawValue);
                break;
            case Barcode.TEXT:
                Log.i("Value", barcode.rawValue);
                break;
        }
    }

    final String noItems = detectedItems.toString();
}
```

My problem is whenever I scan the QR code format result is 'Codabar' instead of QRcode, also whenever I scan barcode the formatted result is 'TEXT' instead of *UPC_E* or *UPC_A*

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the barcode format to setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.ALL_FORMATS)
then only you can use the all the formats.